How to calculate percentage in range slider
This is the second attempt at trying to word out my problem as the first attempt made no sense to me.
I have a range slider which takes in a number such as 408 (could be any number) as the max value and min is 0.
I have a need where something else uses the values in the slider to calculate the width of something but it's min is 0 and max is 1
If a number such as 408 is equal to 1 (which is 100%), 0 is 0 (0% obviously), 0.5 is equal to 204, 0.25 is equal to 102, how would I write a formula I can use in a spreadsheet that would find the value for 0.01? I can use this returned value to work out the width.
I have looked at some of the similar questions but some use a negative min value and others, the answers go straight over my head.
If anyone is able to help, could you please explain the solution in BODMAS as I understand that

A term to search for: "Linear interpolation"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

@Angelica, that just goes way over my head. Do not understand one bit of it

I assume the formula you want is just $$\text{slider} \times \text{maximum}$$

@AdRock Okay, that's fair. I'll try to explain it in a way which doesn't rely on much previous knowledge in a little bit.

Define the position of the slider to be the distance from the minimum value, e.g. $204$. Divide that number by the total range ($408$ in this case) to get $\frac{204}{408}=0.5$. That gives (sliderValue - minValue) / range.

First of all, for this explanation, I'm going to assume a little familiarity with Pre-Algebra. If that is not the case, all you really need to know is that if I say something like "$z=5$", then anywhere else you see $z$, you can replace it with $5$, and then apply BODMAS as usual. Alternatively, if I tell you in English what $z$ is, then you figure out what number should replace $z$ from that information. And if the explanation still goes over your head, fear not---I will have an Excel formula at the end.
I'll start by laying out all the symbols used to represent numbers in your problem: You have an input slider, with a minimum value, a maximum value, and a selected value. Let's have $x$ be the selected value, $x_{min}$ be the minimum value, and $x_{max}$ be the maximum value. In your example, $x_{min}=0$, $x_{max}=408$, and $x$ can be anything as long as $x_{min}\leq x\leq x_{max}$. You also have an output width, with a minimum and maximum. Let's have $y_{min}$ be the minimum output, $y_{max}$ be the maximum, and $y$ be the actual output you want to find. In your example, $y_{min}=0$ and $y_{max}=1$. We don't yet know what number $y$ is, but we're going to figure it out.
Now, the defining property of your problem is that we want $y$ to be the same percentage of the way from $y_{min}$ to $y_{max}$ as the percentage $x$ is from $x_{min}$ to $x_{max}$
We start by finding the percentage of how far $x$ is along from $x_{min}$ to $x_{max}$. We do this by dividing the distance $x$ is from the minimum by the distance between the minimum and maximum:
$$(x-x_{min}) \div (x_{max}-x_{min})$$
Now, we multiply that percentage by total range of the output, to get the distance between the real output and the minimum output:
$$(y_{max}-y_{min}) \times (x-x_{min}) \div (x_{max}-x_{min})$$
Finally, we add the minimum output to get and equation for the real output $y$:
$$y=(y_{max}-y_{min}) \times (x-x_{min}) \div (x_{max}-x_{min})+y_{min}$$
If you replace all the letter-symbols (called variables) with numbers as described above, then you can use BODMAS to find the output.

To implement this in Excel, we first put the numbers for your particular slider into some cells so our formula can reference them. You can use whatever cells you want, but be sure to change the formula to use the right cells if you do.

In A1, put the minimum slider value ($x_{min}$).
In A2, put the maximum slider value ($x_{max}$).
In A3, put the actual slider value ($x$).
In B1, put the minimum output value ($y_{min}$).
In B2, put the maximum output value ($y_{max}$).

In B3, put in the formula for the actual output value. Type or copy/paste in =(B2-B1)*(A3-A1)/(A2-A1)+B1. This will give you the output you want.

One last thing, you mentioned trying to find a slider value from a given width. In that case, the formula also works in reverse: Just swap the minimum/maximum/actual slider input numbers ($x_{min}$, $x_{max}$, $x$) and the width output minimum/maximum/actual numbers ($y_{min}$, $y_{max}$, $y$). This gives the formula:
$$x=(x_{max}-x_{min}) \times (y-y_{min}) \div (y_{max}-y_{min})+x_{min}$$
The Excel sheet can also be modified to reflect this different problem:

Put $y$, the known width, in B3.
Replace A3 with the formula =(A2-A1)*(B3-B1)/(B2-B1)+A1.


Thank you very much @angelica. You're explanation was worded very well and you understood my problem perfectly and knew what I wanted to achieve. I did think it must be simple but i was wrong
